# Stitch Data from One Observable into another Observable with RxJava

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-android, reactivex

I have two Observable streams of type `User` and `Image`:

```
final Observable<List<Image>> images = mNetworkingService.getImages(getToken(context));

final Observable<List<User>> users = mNetworkingService.getUsers()
.onErrorReturn(new Func1<Throwable, List<User>>() {
    @Override
    public List<User> call(Throwable throwable) {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
});
```

I want to assign the user's first and last name to each image object's `fullName` field based off the `userId` contained in both the Image and User objects.

This is what I have so far but not sure if **zip** is the best option. I am close but I get an error when I try to return the collection of image objects as it is expecting a List images but thinks it is just a single image object. If there is a better/cleaner way to do this correlation/assignment I would be interested.

```
return Observable.zip(images, users, 
new Func2<List<Image>, List<User>, Observable<List<Image>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Image>> call(final List<Image> images, List<User> users) {
        for (Image image : images) {
            for (User user : users) {
                if (image.userId.equals(user.userId)) {
                    image.fullName = user.getFullName();
                }
            }
        }
        return Observable.from(images); // Error: Expecting List<Image> but got Image.
    }
}).flatMap(new Func1<Observable<List<Image>>, Observable<List<Image>>>() {
    @Override
    public Observable<List<Image>> call(Observable<List<Image>> it) {
        return it;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

zip() is the right option if you want to act after both requests completed, with both results.

`from()` takes `Iterable<T>` as a parameter and flatten it to `Observable` of T, meaning it will emit each item separately, so that's mean that 
`Observable.from(images)` returns `Observable<Image>`, whereas you defined the zipper method as returns `Observable<List<Image>>` so there's your mismatch, and compile error.

**But**, anyhow, you shouldn't return `Observable` from the zipper method, as the zipper just expect you to transform the multiple object you get, to single object.
for each 'zip' of 2 items emission it will execute the zipper, and you'll get `onNext()` with the resulted zipped object, but in your case you will emit **Observable** object with each `onNext()`, this is probably not what you want.

so to sum it up, you should probably want something like this:

```
Observable.zip(images, users,
            new Func2<List<Image>, List<User>, List<Image>>() {
                @Override
                public List<Image> call(final List<Image> images, List<User> users) {
                    for (Image image : images) {
                        for (User user : users) {
                            if (image.userId.equals(user.userId)) {
                                image.fullName = user.getFullName();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return images; 
                }
            })
            .subscribe(new Action1<List<Image>>() {
                @Override
                public void call(List<Image> images) {
                    //do something with the list of images combined with user data
                }
            });
```